# What language features does Ruby borrow from CLU?

Tags: ruby

I have read in Ola Bini's blog that Ruby has influenced by CLU language, but besides the multiple assignment I'm not sure what other influences exist.  Any guidance and simple examples would be most appreciative.

Comment: @close voters: How is this question off topic?

Comment: it is not off topic. Stackoverflow has too many narrow-minded participants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time matz ever mentioned CLU was when talking about iterators. Everything else is more or less directly from Smalltalk, Lisp, Flavors and Perl. Singleton classes seem to be unique to Ruby, though they are related to Smalltalk's metaclasses.

Comment: Were blocks only used for iterators in CLU, or did they have other uses?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how abstract you want to get: CLU had iterators, exceptions, memory management, and  was sort-of OO.

It was actually kind of interesting.